# Supercollider: Include additional source code file

Tags: software

Is there a way in a Supercollider source code file to include another source code file from disk, like the "include"-statement does in C++?

I assume there must be a way to do it, but I haven't managed to find any example by googling.

Comment: Welcome to our site Elias. I'm not sure this is on topic here.  While we do allow music software questions it typically isn't this low level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supercollider appears to be able to execute code from external files, though whether this is an include-into-the-current-namespace or something-run-in-a-new-environment I don't know:

http://doc.sccode.org/Classes/String.html#-load

A recursive grep for "loadPath" should turn up examples:

http://supercolliderbook.net/code/code.zip

Answer (score 0):

// =====================================================================
// FILE: utilityFunctions.scd
// =====================================================================

```
/*This file contains some utility functions.
You can 'import' these functions using executeFile.

*NONE* of the vars in the 'imported' file end up 
in the scope of the file doing the 'importing'

'import' this with something like:
var utils  = this.executeFile(path-to-this-file);

If BOTH FILES are in the same directory you can do this:
var utils  = this.executeFile(Document.current.dir ++ "/utilityFunctions.scd");

Then you can refer to the functions like this:
utils[\fmtInt].(1234567); // this returns "1,234,567"

You could also do this:
var fmtInt = utils[\fmtInt];
fmtInit.(7654321); // this returns "7,654,321"
*/

var fmtInt = { arg num, sep=",", groupSize=3;
  var str = num.asInteger.asString;
  var len = str.size;
  var numSeps = ((len-1)/groupSize).floor.asInteger;
  var firstSep = len - (numSeps*groupSize);
  var stop = len - groupSize;
  var out=str;
  firstSep.forBy(stop, groupSize,
    {|pos, itr|
      var ins = pos + itr;
      out = out.insert(ins, sep);
  });
  out; // return result
};

var readStr0 = {arg file, max=20;
  var zeroByte = 0.asAscii;  // zero byte
  var str = "";
  block {|break|
    max.do {|i|
      var char = file.getChar;
      if (char == zeroByte) { break.value(999); };
      str = str++char;
    };
  };
  str;  // return result
};

var functions = Dictionary.new(2);

functions.add(\fmtInt -> fmtInt);
functions.add(\readStr0 -> readStr0);

functions;  // return the dictionary of functions
```

// =====================================================================
// END OF FILE: utilityFunctions.scd
// =====================================================================

// =====================================================================
// FILE: testUtilityFunctions.scd
// =====================================================================

```
/*TestUtilityFunctions*/
(
// this assumes the test file is in the same dir as the code file
var dir = Document.current.dir;
var name = "/utilityFunctions.scd";
var path = dir ++ name;
var utils  = this.executeFile(path);

var f1 = utils[\fmtInt];
var f2 = utils[\readStr0];
var d1 = f1.def;
var a1 = d1.argNames;

postf("\nTesting the (import of) the functions in file: %\n", name);
postf("utils is: %\n", utils);
postf("f1 should be a Function, it is: %\n", f1);
postf("f2 should be a Function, it is: %\n", f2);
postf("d1 should be a FunctionDef, it is: %\n", d1);
postf("a1 should be the args of f1, it is: %\n", a1);
postln("Check that names did not bleed in from imported file:");
postf("~functions should be nil, it is: %\n", ~functions);
postf("~fmtInt should be nil, it is: %\n", ~fmtInt);
postln("try one of the functions:");
postf("f1.(12345) is: %\n", f1.(12345));
postf("utils[\\fmtInt].(5678) is: %\n", utils[\fmtInt].(5678));

postln("'functions.postln;' should return: ERROR: Variable 'functions' not defined.");
/*functions.postln;*/

"\n";
)
```

// ========================================================================
// END OF FILE: testUtilityFunctions.scd
// ========================================================================

Comment: Hi, welcome to Music: Practice & Theory.  Can you please [edit] your answer to fix the formatting, and to add a paragraph or two of explanation about what this code is/does. Thanks!